Json script for Chrome extension only runs the first time URL is entered
I am working on building a Chrome extension that uses CSS and HTML elements to block certain parts of the YouTube page. The issue is, the Json script only seems to execute the CSS files the FIRST time I go on the url; any pages/redirects afterwards requires for a hard refresh/reload to get the script working properly again for that page.
For example: if I go onto www.youtube.com the json script will work (using the homepage.css file), but if I were to search up a channel name (which relies on a file called channel.css) the page will appear to behave normally, ignoring my channel.css file.
I am using Chrome's "load unpacked" to load my extension and here is the json file I am using:
(note: all the css files work properly, I just can't get them to continuously work without refreshing each YouTube page)
{
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "name": "Locked In for YouTube - Productivity & Focus",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Stay 'locked in' by removing distracting elements that keep you away from your work such as recommended, Shorts, trending tab, etc.",
  "permissions": ["activeTab"],
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["*://www.youtube.com/*"],
      "css": ["homepage.css"]
    },
    {
      "matches": ["*://www.youtube.com/feed*"],
      "css": ["feed.css"]
    },
    {
      "matches": ["*://www.youtube.com/results*"],
      "css": ["results.css"]
    },
    {
      "matches": ["*://www.youtube.com/watch*"],
      "css": ["watch.css"]
    },
    {
      "matches": ["*://www.youtube.com/@*"],
      "css": ["channel.css"]
    }
  ]
}


Also if it helps, my file tree looks like the following (they are all in the same directory):
core/
|
├──manifest.json
├──channel.css
├──feed.css
├──homepage.css
├──results.css
├──watch.css


YouTube is a SPA (Single-Page Application) site that fakes the URL via history API and updates DOM in the same physical page, whereas content scripts are only injected when the page is first created, not for fake URL changes.
You'll need to inject a single CSS file on the entire *://www.youtube.com/* and use selectors that are specific to a given kind of pages.
manifest.json (don't forget document_start to ensure there's no FOUC):
  "content_scripts": [{
    "matches": ["*://www.youtube.com/*"],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "css": ["youtube.css"]
  }]

youtube.css:
body:has(ytd-watch-flexy:not([hidden])) {
  ytd-app {
    color: green;
  }
  ytd-compact-video-renderer {
    color: yellow;
  }
}


I see. Unfortunately youtube has many html elements that are named the same (like video-grid-renderer) and so if I make changes to it on www.youtube.com the changes will carry over to --say for example-- if I wanted to browse through a channel which also implemented video-grid-renderer to display the channel's videos. Is there a workaround for this? Or maybe even is there a way to make sure that the script is re-injected everytime the DOM changes?


It should be possible to use nested CSS with :has selector as shown in my answer. 2) Alternatively, to reinject it you'll have to observe navigation and insert the CSS styles manually either as DOM style in the content script or using chrome.scripting.insertCSS and removeCSS in the background script.

